# How to make a scrollable, clickable list of items in Dojo?

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I'm totally new to Dojo (using 1.3 via Google's XD), and want to try to do things the 'right way', but don't see an obvious dojo.layout.*Container for this.

Basically, I have a UI with a list of categories on the left, and then a list of data on the right.

So say there are 20 categories and each one has 20 items in it.  I want to be able to click on a category and then display the appropriate list on the right.

But I don't see a Container that just holds a list of ContentPanes.  My gut feeling is that the layout should be:

- BorderContainer:

  - leading:  ???Container
  - - 1 ContentPane per category
  - center:   ???Container
  - - 1 ContentPane per item in selected category.

But I have no idea what that ???Container should be.

Some options I've thought of:

- Using a dojox.Tree for the Categories.  Not ideal, since my categories aren't heirarchical, and I'd have to alter the CSS to hide the +/- and lines.
- Using a diji.Menu for the categories.  Close, but I want to highlight the selected category, and it doesn't feel like Menus are made for that.
- Building my own _Container subclass.  Seems doable, but is that really necessary?
- Using Templated Widgets.  Seems maybe the best approach I've found, but I'm unclear if that's really what I want to do.

So, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want dijit.layout.StackContainer.

Comment: What's the best way to make the stack 'buttons' stack vertically instead of horizontally?

Comment: How about making them display:block?